# MSBuild failing on external project's dependencies

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I've looked at every other question similar to this with no luck.

Here's the solution setup:

```
External Solution
    - Project A
    - Project B (dependency on project A, and on EntityFramework)

Primary Solution
    - Project A (included through "Add Existing Project" dialog)
    - Project B (same as above)
    - Web project
```

When I try to check in this primary solution, the build server fails saying things like the following:

```
CodeFileInProjectB.cs (4): The type or namespace name 'Infrastructure' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
CodeFileInProjectB.cs (11): The type or namespace name 'DbPropertyEntry' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

It's clearly failing to resolve project B's dependency on EF. I've checked all the references, I even did that thing where you make sure `<Private>True</Private>` is in the csproj file.

Did I reference the external projects wrong? What the heck is going on? I've tried eight times already with different advice from various SO questions, and no luck.

Comment: EF is referenced as a NuGet package?

Comment: @GiulioVian Yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches: or you check-in the packages with your code or you [get the packages on-the-fly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/08/27/nuget-package-restore-with-team-foundation-build.aspx) while building.
Pros and cons and detailed steps are in the [next version](https://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/) of ALM Rangers' guidance.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Giulio Vian's remark about the NuGet package restore, make sure project B is referencing EF correctly by opening its project file (i.e. `b.csproj`) with any text editor and verify the `HintPath` elements are correct. An extra or missing `..\` will cause the build to fail.

A valid reference example:

```
<Reference Include="EntityFramework">
   <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.2\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```